# How to exit a payment in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, in-app-purchase, storekit

When a user is about to purchase an in-app purchase, a small popup comes up where they enter their Apple ID and password to confirm the purchase.

But if my app detects something, I want to exit this payment widget and stop the payment.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

This is a system dialog, so you do not have any means to close it.